# How can I change default value of toggle Switch from Settings.bundle

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, toggleswitch

i want to change default value programmatically of toggle switch from settings bundle. If someone can help me please with that.
[image]

Comment: your question not seems much clear ? do you want to change settings of setting app of ios programmatically ?

Comment: no i create file settings.bundle and add toggle switch and have root.plist in this plist i want to change default value of this toggle switch from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `register(defaults:)` to set default values for your UserDefaults values, like so:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
   "toggleSwitchKey": true
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that not work sorry. This is my code: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"enabled_preference": [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}];

Comment: Are you sure "Default Value" is the settings key of your toggle switch?

Comment: No that is [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"enabled_preference": [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}];

Comment: Please show the full settings plist entry for this switch.

Comment: i adding image.

Comment: So your code does set the default value to NO, which is already in the plist. What do you expect should happen in that case?

Comment: No i also want to set it like yes and when i put this code with Yes  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"enabled_preference": [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]}] also not work.

Comment: I make it, to change value must to make like this :[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"enabled_preference"];, with register not working . But thank you very much.

Comment: Well, that's changing the actual value of the switch, not its default.